# Download a github account

Tags: github, download

Suppose I see a Github account such as [Mono](https://github.com/mono) with many repos in it.

What do I do to download all of the repos at once?

I don't want to have to download each zip individually.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to *clone* all the repo of the organization Mono, they wouldn't have to be zip.

Zip or clones, there is no native way offered by GitHub to get all the repos in one click.

But, [from this gist](https://gist.github.com/caniszczyk/3856584), you still can get them in one command line:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/orgs/mono/repos?per_page=200 | ruby -rubygems -e 'require "json"; JSON.load(STDIN.read).each { |repo| %x[git clone #{repo["ssh_url"]} ]}'
```

You can replace `ssh_url` by `clone_url` if you want to clone them using an https address.

If you really don't want to clone them, but only want to get the archive, you would have to get from that one-line the `archive_url` part, and tweak it to get the archive of the `master` branch (for example).

Comment: I have never done much work with Github
So, do I enter that in the standard windows command prompt?
If so, where do I get curl from?

Comment: @LiamFlaherty `curl.exe` is part of your msysgit distribution. But you also can get it from §Gnu on Windows (https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki)